# Error datatable:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

estoy usando datatables para mostrar información de una tabla, esta información la estoy tratando de cargar con ajax, es un json que hice con php y la función json_encode.

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tabla').dataTable({
                "ajax": {
                   "url": "data.php"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Pero me aparece el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   jquery.dataTables.min.js:62

y esta es una parte del data.php

```
[ 
   { 
      "id":"1029",
      "nombre":"Luis",
      "email":"luis@gmail.com",
      "estatus":"1"
   },
   { 
      "id":"1028",
      "nombre":"Ernesto",
      "email":"ernesto@hotmail.com",
      "estatus":"1"
   }
]
```

Comment: Olvidaste poner el código más importante: Donde generas el contenido, lo cargas por AJAX y lo pasas a JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pasa que tu tabla HTML que estás usando tiene más o menos campos de los que deberían tener, es decir, si estás regresando cuatro datos, los mismos los debes de especificar en tu tabla HTML, así como también en el código jquery en donde construyes el datatables por ajax.

Te dejo cómo debería de ser tu código `jquery`, tu `HTML` considerando que `data.php` te regresa la estructura que mencionas en tu pregunta.

código `jquery`

```
$('#mi-tabla-ajax').DataTable({
    "language": {
      "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
    },
    "bDestroy": true,
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": "data.php",
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [

        { "data" : "id" },            
        { "data" : "nombre" },         
        { "data" : "email" },
        { "data" : "estatus" },
    ]                               
});
```

HTML

```
<table width="100%" id="mi-tabla-ajax">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Estatus</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Por favor nota que tanto tu código en la tabla HTML tiene los mismos campos que especificas al crear el datatables en tu código jquery.